# How to sort documents by a field in an array with condition on another array field?

Tags: mongodb

I have this kind of document in a MongoDB 7 database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("65f40c61fc6af76116039021"),
    "cells" : [
        {
            "key" : "person.id",
            "type" : "TEXT",
            "value" : ObjectId("65f40c61fc6af76116039020")
        },
        {
            "key" : "person.name",
            "type" : "TEXT",
            "value" : "yelling_indigo_squid"
        },
        {
            "value" : NumberInt(31),
            "key" : "person.age",
            "type" : "NUMBER"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a wildcard index on `cells.$**`.

I want to order by `cells.value` if `cells.key` is `person.name`.

I tried this aggregation:

```
db.getCollection("row").aggregate(
    [ 
        {
            "$addFields" : {
                "cells" : {
                    "$map" : {
                        "input" : "$cells",
                        "as" : "cell",
                        "in" : {
                            "$cond" : {
                                "if" : {
                                    "$eq" : [
                                        "$$cell.key",
                                        "person.name"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "then" : {
                                    "$mergeObjects" : [
                                        "$$cell",
                                        {
                                            "nameValue" : "$$cell.value"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "else" : "$$cell"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$sort" : {
                "cells.nameValue" : NumberInt(1)
            }
        }
    ], 
    {
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

But it doesn't fit in memory and I want a solution which use indexes. I worked from scratch so I can modify the schema if needed.

Sort by the `cells.key` `person.name` is just an example. I want to be able to sort by any `cells.key`.

The `row` collection will have certainly more than 100 millions entries so I need the most optimized aggregation possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to flatten your array entries into individual documents like this if you find yourself working at the `cells` level alot.

```js
[
  {
    "key": "person.id",
    "originalId": ObjectId("65f40c61fc6af76116039021"),
    "type": "TEXT",
    "value": ObjectId("65f40c61fc6af76116039020")
  },
  {
    "key": "person.name",
    "originalId": ObjectId("65f40c61fc6af76116039021"),
    "type": "TEXT",
    "value": "yelling_indigo_squid"
  },
  {
    "key": "person.age",
    "originalId": ObjectId("65f40c61fc6af76116039021"),
    "type": "NUMBER",
    "value": 31
  }
]
```

You can still keep a wildcard index at root level:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**" : 1 } )
```

The query can be simplified to this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "key": "person.name"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      value: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OxIJ8ub2M6e)

---

[Code for migration/refactoring](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2MepUGmioaJ)

Comment: This solution will generate 10x more documents and I need after an aggregation to merge documents together in a row. Moreover, a row is composed of those three cells not just one.

Comment: @FranckAnso not sure what does that mean...? the raw `_id` is kept as `originalId` in the migration code so you can use that to group back your original form if needed.

Comment: @FranckAnso What is more, if you are really having a lot of `cells` entries in a single document, it is not likely to survive the [16MB single document size limit](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#:~:text=Document%20Size%20Limit,MongoDB%20provides%20the%20GridFS%20API.)

Comment: No problem for the 16MB limit but I can have more than three cells by row. I don't see the originalId field in your proposal but I don't see how you re-create the row document effectively after having filtered documents. Could you explain?

Comment: @FranckAnso Actually I don't fully understand your "merge" requirement right now. From your example, I can only see it is purely duplicating a field(without requiring information from other array entries). Can you [edit] your question to include an example where reference to information other than those in the array entry itself? Nevertheless, you can always use `$setWindowFields` to reconstruct the "row" like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r_221zf4PBj)

Comment: I don't see how I can more explain my requirements... Think of this collection like a google sheet: a document is equivalent to a row and a row is composed of cells. In google sheet, you can order rows by adding a sort on the column. I want to do the same thing with my collections of rows. I want to order all rows by giving the key field. The value field represents the content of the cell.